# Python - Data Transformation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

I am trying to convert this "dataframe" into this other "dataframe" in python:

From this:

```
job_posting,Job_description,rating,company_name,big_data,spark,hadoop,power bi,excel,python,azure,Founded,Location
1,blalbblablabla,3,Exson,1,0,1,,,,0,2007,US
2,blalbblablabla,4,1,,,,1,1,,0,2010,EU
3,blalbblablabla,0,Wine20,1,1,,,,1,1,2000,LA
```

To this:

```
job_posting,Job_description,rating,company_name,technologies_required,Founded,Location
1,blalbblablabla,3,Exson,big_data, hadoop,2007,US
2,blalbblablabla,4,1,power bi, excel,2010,EU
3,blalbblablabla,0,Wine20,big_data, spark, python, azure,2000,LA
```

This is what it could look like:
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

New revised code. @Timeless thanks!

```
# Create "technologies_required"
df['technologies_required'] = df.apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x.index[x.eq(1) & ~x.index.isin(['job_posting', 'for_example_rating'])]), axis=1)

# Reorder columns
new_df = df[['job_posting', 'for_example_rating', 'technologies_required']]
```

Now, it doesn't matter if any other column includes a number 1 in their rows.

Unfortunately I don't know if this is good or bad practice :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to [*boolean-index*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) the columns names :

```
techs = df.apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x.index[x.eq(1)]), axis=1)
#techs = df.apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x.eq(1).loc[lambda s: s].index), axis=1) #variant

out = df[["job_posting"]].join(techs.rename("technologies_required"))
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   job_posting technologies_required
0         5674       big_data, spark
1        13037                 excel
2         4377        powerbi, azure
```

***Update :***

> There is a little problem in this code: If job_posting or any other
> column (not techs) has a value of 1, then that column is included as
> well.

```
lcols = ["job_posting", "lob_description", "rating", "company_name"]
rcols = ["Founded", "Location"]

techs = df.drop(columns=lcols+rcols).apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x.index[x.eq(1)]), axis=1)

out = pd.concat([df[lcols], techs.rename("technologies_required"), df[rcols]], axis=1)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   job_posting lob_description  rating company_name           technologies_required  Founded Location
0            1  blalbblablabla       3        Exson                big data, hadoop     2007       US
1            2  blalbblablabla       1            1                 excel, power bi     2010       EU
2            3  blalbblablabla       0       Wine20  azure, big data, python, spark     2000       LA
```

Comment: This is Timeless... thanks alot 

I think I understand what you did.
1. created a new dataframe with True values called "techs"
2. collected column names from "techs" where values were True
3. joined column name from "techs" with a comma
4. joined column "job_posting" from original df with "techs"

Comment: There is a little problem in this code: If job_posting or any other column (not techs) has a value of 1, then that column is included as well. Based on your code I posted (above) a revised version.

Comment: No, that’s because uou did not mention that at first. Can you make an example that describe your real dataset ?

Comment: My bad Timeless. In case you still want to see an example, I updated the data and snapshot above. Just so you know, your code helped me alot.

Comment: There is no problem ;) I updated my answer. Can you check it please and see if it's good ?

Comment: Again, timeless! Thank you. I assume that the separation of lcols and rcols was for educational purposes only, correct? It works great!

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, that's correct and also to keep the right order of columns. Happy coding ;)